# PDO returns SUM as string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with PDO. Every time I want to fetch the sum of a column, I get the value, but it is the wrong field type. When I tried fetching other values from a table PDO returned also only strings. After chaning some settings, the value types for generic table queries are right, but not the sum.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=something, 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) AS balance FROM deposits");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result['balance']);
}
// string(7) "5178.96"
```

'amount' is a decimal by the way. I've heard PDO doesn't like decimals, but it doesn't work with float either.

Comment: I think you'd have to cast it as an int/float. You could do it in PHP or mysql. PHP https://eval.in/657637, MYSQL `CAST(SUM(amount) AS FLOAT) AS balance`